# Database wiped after testing in Laravel

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing, laravel-5, phpunit

I'm new at Testing, so I was following a tutorial. The Database setting I set into like this:

```
'sqlite' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => ':memory:',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],
```

and in the phpunit.xml I made configuration like this:

```
<php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="DATABASE_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    </php>
```

I'm not sure what's going on, the database seed that I created using factory is always missing and the database tables either, left only with a migration table.

**so what happened and how can I fix it?**

Answer (score 0):

I was going to post it as a comment but due to lack of reputation I was not able to do so.

Things you can try to solve your current problem:-

- Check your **.env** file. The database configuration must be appropriate to join the connection.
- Check the **laravel.log** file in order to view the error generated during your testing.
- Check your **migration** file and **seeder** file.

As you said in the question that neither data is seeded nor tables are found, clearly hints regarding error in database configuration or migration file.

Hope this helps.

Edit:- you can try a workaround for this. In your **config/databae.php** below *mysql* add:-

```
 'mysql_testing' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('TESTING_DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('TESTING_DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('TESTING_DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('TESTING_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

And now you must entry the details in your **.env** file:-

```
TESTING_DB_HOST=localhost
TESTING_DB_DATABASE=homestead_testing
TESTING_DB_USERNAME=homestead
TESTING_DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Note:- While migration use the following migration command only during the testing purpose.

`php artisan migrate --database=mysql_testing`

Its for mysql testing database but you can likewise do for sqlite also.

Comment: what setting that can make me to join the connection? anyway my dev env is in mysql, and my test only i'm using sqlite.

Comment: The database you use for your dev purpose should be different than the testing purpose as it will create dummy data. Wait I will edit the answer.

Comment: ah ok, i will give it try. so do you have any example using sqllite and memory? it seem more practice since i don't have to remove manually aftar i do the testing.

Comment: oh and one more thing what is the setting for the phpunit.xml for your solution?

Comment: I guess you have edited your dev database configuration in order to achieve for testing. Don't mix it up. Use separate db(mysql) and separate config for dev as well as separate db(sqlite) and separate config for testing

Comment: i do as your suggestion above, i make 2 different database, and still this testing still wiping all my database data although i already set the in phpunit.xml either.

Comment: are you using the config:clear command before executing your test? If not, do use "php artisan config:clear" command.

Comment: I do, since i search and find that i have to clear the config. but in my case it's useless, i do a lot of config clear but still it wipe my database.

Comment: lots of mess up eh! I would recommend you to begin your process right from the start to let make yourself aware of the bug and fix it accordingly. I don't have the whole source code so I would not be able to stretch more on this. [kindly refer this for basics](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/testing#environment)

Comment: lol yeah, it's ok, i spend almost all days and googling only told me the solution is config:clear. but it doesn't work in my case. actually it's a fresh project with 2 model. i just create it for testing, but it give me a lot of trouble

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem it's because i'm using Database Migration in my test. it have a function to rollback, so i just uncomment it:

```
$this->beforeApplicationDestroyed(function () {
            //$this->artisan('migrate:rollback');

            RefreshDatabaseState::$migrated = false;
        });
```